# Automatically send an email associated with a case

Tags: apex, marketing-cloud, process-builder, case, servicecloud

We use Marketing Cloud to send surveys to contacts about specific products. When a customer completes a survey, a journey creates a case with their comments (Case Description) and survey rating (Rating__c, numerical). The Case record type is set depending on their rating (a 1 or 2 rating would be a Complaint record type for example). The subject is "Survey for X Product".

When a customer gives us a rating of 1 or 2 with no comments, we want to automatically send them an email template (Negative Survey Email Template) and close the case. This is to save our agents time so that they can prioritize helping those who did give us feedback/comments.

Originally, I had thought to have Marketing Cloud send the email and then create the case with a Closed Status. However, this does not associate the email with the case, so if the customer responds it will create a new case instead of reopening the original.

I tried using Auto Response Rules, and received the following error:
*This email address is the same as an email address used for Email-to-Case routing. Please enter a different email address.*
Our only other email is a noreply email, which I do not want to use.

I have now set up a Flow to trigger a Send Email Action. I have successfully sent the email using this flow, however it did not associate with the case record that triggered the flow. I have found several stack exchange posts detailing possible ways to expose a Case Thread ID and will be trying that next - if I can expose the ID maybe I can use it as a merge field in the email so that the reply will come back to the case at least.

Any ideas are appreciated. Thank you